# Is there any app for electronic signature solution?

Tags: macos, applications, pdf

Is there any app for signing the documents (PDFs) by electronic signature?

Similar to on-line solutions such as HelloSign, EchoSign, XolidoSign, eSignly, DocuSign, Signsquid, RightSignature, PDFFiller or free [Fill and Sign PDF Forms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.binarysolutions.fasp) (Android app), but as an application for OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview can sign documents, since v5, currently at v7 - 
[Sign a PDF document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5946)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using PDFPen, from smileonmymac.com, for years just for this purpose. In newer forms, it's possible to fill and print them in Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Ultra Signatures? This is a free tool, but has all the features that you find in a professional version. With Ultra Signatures you can quickly convert a PDF or Word document into gather electronic signatures, and share this document also. This has other features also, like Document Management, document merging, Workflow process, Custom Forms,  the nice thing is it has a free version with all these features but there is a limit on how many documents you can use in a month.

Comment: It might help to add a link to the product page. Also, if it is your product, please state so.